# Why does Visual Studio Code (VSC) display nothing when I open a folder containing files (html, css, js) (occurs intermittently)?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ide

At times I open a folder in Visual Studio Code and it displays a blank UI (no tab navigation on the left and no document view on the right.
There are some menus though.

[image: Visual Studio Code is blank]

If I open the outer folder then I see the content... Red box highlight is the same folder that doesn't display properly when I open folder directly.

[image: outer folder displays content]

**Additional Information**

1. Version: 1.53.2
2. Commit: 622cb03f7e070a9670c94bae1a45d78d7181fbd4
3. Date: 2021-02-11T11:48:44.518Z
4. Electron: 11.2.1
5. Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
6. Node.js: 12.18.3
7. V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
8. OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-65-generic (Ubuntu 20.04)

**One Guess At What Is Happening**

I believe it might be something to do with git and hidden files.  I restored a repo from a git repository.

Comment: Be sure you are opening the project solution as that’s what will allow you view the files in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd.  I was just trying things and I saw that the File...Close Editor...choice was available.  I clicked it once and it flashed.
I clicked that menu item again and the right side (black area) closed and I could see the nav bar at the left.

[image: Close Editor]

After that I could see my project files again.

[image: Success - can view files]